# Build JSON output from a nested list

Tags: jquery, json, list

I've the following unordered list:

```
<ul class="primary">
    <li id="1"><span>Product Family A</span>
       <ul class="secondary">
           <li><span>A.1</span></li>
           <li><span>A.2</span></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="2"><span>Product Family B</span>
       <ul class="secondary">
           <li><span>B.1</span></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    etc...
</ul>
```

I'd like to generate the output below with jQuery. Can someone help?

```
product_family:[{
   id:1,
   products:[{
      model: A1,
      model: A2
}],
product_family:[{
   id:2,
   products:[{
      model: B1
}]
```

THanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each and http://api.jquery.com/children and http://api.jquery.com/text

Comment: Your proposed output is nonsensical.  JS/JSON field names are unique within a particular object; with duplicate keys of `product_family` and `model` within the same object, the second instance will just blow away the first.  You're trying to treat JSON like XML and you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var out = [];
$('ul.primary > li').each(function(index, val) {
    out[index] = {
        product_family : this.id,
        products: []
    };
    $('ul > li', this).each(function() {
        out[index].products.push({
            model: $('span', this).text()
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks much, this is close. It's missing the 'id' as one of the key in the product_family. Right now it's printing out as such: [{"product_family":"1","products":[{"model":"A.1"},{"model":"A.2"}]}].

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this part is invalid:

```
products:[{
    model: A1,
    model: A2
}],
```

I'll assume you meant to write this:

```
products:[
    { model: A1 },
    { model: A2 }
}],
```

You can use something like this:

```
var pf = [];
$("ul.primary").children("li").each(function(i,e) {
    var products = [];
    $(e).find('ul').find('span').each(function(i2,e2) {
        products.push({ model: $(e2).find('ul') });
    });
    pf.push( {
        id: (i+1),
        products: products
    });
});
```